# How do I run some code on every route in React except for a specific one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to the attach an external script that should run on every page/route except for 2 in particular.

I have a Navbar component that is rendered for every route. So, I added a script tag in that component. Like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
if(location.pathname !== "/page/sehat-a-z" || location.pathname !== "/page/sehat-a-z" ) {
appendScript("url")
window.wa_btnSetting = {"btnColor":"#16BE45","ctaText":"WhatsApp Us","cornerRadius":40,"marginBottom":20,"marginLeft":20,"marginRight":20,"btnPosition":"right","whatsAppNumber":"+111111111111","welcomeMessage":"Hello","zIndex":999999,"btnColorScheme":"light"};
window.onload = () => {
_waEmbed(wa_btnSetting);
    };
    }
  }, [])
```

Here,

`if(location.pathname !== "/page/sehat-a-z" || location.pathname !== "/page/sehat-a-z" )`

is the url for pages that I don't want to attach an script on. But, it's not working properly. When I go to this page, the script doesn't run, but when I navigate from this page to other pages, the script doesn't run there too.

Comment: I really don't understand why do you have the same pathname twice in your if statement. How about just ```if(location.pathname !== "/page/sehat-a-z")``` ?

Comment: I must've forgot to add `/` at the end for the second pathname

Comment: well then if you add the ```/``` at the end of the second you'll have an issue. Because if it's the first path, then the second will evaluate to true and if it the second, the first one will evaluate to true. So either way it will be true. So you'll want to change your ```||``` in a ```&&```. So that if it's not the first one, AND not the second one, then ...

Answer (score 1):

You are using `window.onLoad` which might not be running on every route. It must be running when you refresh the page.

Also you are running **useEffect** without the dependency array. So if your app is SPA then your navbar should be loading once only and hence not running your script.

To get this working, add a dependency which is the route of the app, whenever that changes fire the useEffect and inside that you can look for the which route to run on.

```
const route = window.location.pathname

useEffect(() => {
 // Your code goes here

}, [route])
```

Comment: How do I pass the route in dependency array?

Comment: @Zain I have updated my answer, check that out.

Comment: I did add `location.pathname` in the dependency array but it's not working.

Comment: Try logging to console, what is the value of the route when you navigate? Try logging if your useEffect is getting called. If your useEffect is getting called then you have just one thing which is running your script. Try removing that from window.onload and put that simply inside your if condition which checks for the route.

Comment: I logged `location.pathname` inside the `if` condition and it's logging the correct route.

Comment: Still not working ? Tell me what you want to do exactly...as in the feature ?

Comment: I just want to add that script on every page except for one specific page.

Comment: Did you remove it from window.onload ? If you have removed it from window.onload and your code is coming till the script call, then your code is working fine, you will have to check if your script is working fine or not?

Comment: The script is working fine but the problem is, it's working on every page. I don't want it to work for the route that I've defined. 

I didn't remove window.onload().

Comment: I removed from `window.onload` but now it's giving an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: _waEmbed is not defined`

Comment: I see, i think since it's getting into window once...and hence running on every page. You will have to update the script for this. Inside your script you should do this check.